# nginx reverse proxy ssl for multiple ports

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured my ssl for mydomain.com using nginx reverse proxy, so it works fine on https://example.com, but I need the same ssl certificate to work on port 8081, this https://example.com:8081 should work.

I have no clue even after multiple tries, this is my working nginx conf

```
server {


    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}




server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1260;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    }


server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;



    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Any help is much appreciated as I am really struggling here.

Comment: You need to use `listen 8081 ssl;` and copy over the `ssl_` directives from the other `server` block.

Comment: yes :( I tried that, without adding listen 443 lines, because it threw me error..I had remaining 4 ssl lines on the other server block, but no avail